# Reading a specific part of a text file in C++

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm reading a file with `<fstream>`, and said file contains lines like this:

```
Name=Cecil
Age=34
Born=London
//etc.
```

For the sake of the example, lets say I would like to assign `34` to the variable `int age`. This would mean that I have to find which line starts with `Age`, and then extract the value `34` after the equal sign.

Later on I would like to alter this value in the program, and replace it in the file, so `34` would become  for example `35`, so again, I have to find this specific part of the file and write there.

It seems like a basic task, yet I couldn't find any good examples so far. Maybe it would be better to store my data as JSON or XML and use a library for this purpose?

Comment: reader for `ini` may fit, for example https://github.com/benhoyt/inih  or  https://github.com/brofield/simpleini

Comment: This would be just what I need, however I'm struggling with installing it. I always get the error `undefined reference to 'INIReader::INIReader(std::string)'`. I've placed the INIReader.h and the ini.h files in the include library, and the INIReader.cpp file next to the main.cpp. I'm using C::B. I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: do you actually compile and link with `INIReader.cpp` (see [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Data looks like Key-Value pairs, so here is an Object-Oriented way to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct DATA
{
    struct PAIR
    {
            string m_szComponentSeparator;
            string m_szKey;
            string m_szValue;
            PAIR()
            {
                    m_szComponentSeparator = "=";
            }
            void Read(ifstream &_inFile)
            {
                    string szLine;
                    _inFile >> szLine;
                    size_t pos = szLine.find(m_szComponentSeparator);
                    m_szKey = szLine.substr(0, pos);
                    m_szValue = szLine.substr(pos + 1);
            }
            void Write(ofstream &_outFile)
            {
                    _outFile << m_szKey << m_szComponentSeparator << m_szValue << endl;
            }
            int To_int()
            {
                    return atoi(m_szValue.c_str());
            }
            void SetAs_int(int _iValue)
            {
                    char szBuf[32] = {0};
                    snprintf(szBuf, sizeof(szBuf), "%d", _iValue);
                    m_szValue = szBuf;
            }

    };

    PAIR m_stName;
    PAIR m_stAge;
    PAIR m_stBorn;
    void Read(string _szFilepath)
    {
            ifstream inFile(_szFilepath.c_str());
            m_stName.Read(inFile);
            m_stAge.Read(inFile);
            m_stBorn.Read(inFile);
    }
    void Write(string _szFilepath)
    {
            ofstream outFile(_szFilepath.c_str());
            m_stName.Write(outFile);
            m_stAge.Write(outFile);
            m_stBorn.Write(outFile);
    }
    void Print()
    {
            cout << m_stName.m_szKey << m_stName.m_szComponentSeparator << m_stName.m_szValue << endl;
            cout << m_stAge.m_szKey << m_stAge.m_szComponentSeparator << m_stAge.m_szValue << endl;
            cout << m_stBorn.m_szKey << m_stBorn.m_szComponentSeparator << m_stBorn.m_szValue << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    string szInputFile = "in.txt";
    string szOutputFile = "out.txt";

    DATA oData;
    oData.Read(szInputFile);
    oData.Print();

    int age = oData.m_stAge.To_int();
    age = 35;
    oData.m_stAge.SetAs_int(age);

    cout << "after modification:" << endl;
    oData.Print();

    oData.Write(szOutputFile);

    return 0;
}

//Output:
Name=Cecil
Age=34
Born=London
after modification
Name=Cecil
Age=35
Born=London
```

Comment: Any reason for down voting?

Comment: Even though I've not implemented your full code, you have given me some good ideas on how to solve this. I've created my own method with the use of `find()`, `substr()` and `atoi()`. It looks like I needed those functions. (I don't know who down voted you.)

Comment: Probably downvoted, because code-only answers aren't exactly helpful. It's the old *"handing out the fish"*. A more valuable answer would contain a rationale. Rationale is important so that you know when good advice starts to turn bad.

Answer (score 2):

That's a basic need but not a basic implementation because files are just streams of bytes and have no structure. That means that you need to implement some algorithm to interpret/parse the data written. You should know that you can't delete something in a file nor you can insert; I mean there is no single operation that makes the trick and that's a problem in your case because if you want to replace say 34 with 7, length of that information is different and you would like to delete one char (impossible) and replace the other (this is possible); same reasoning when replacing 34 with 103. This is why databases are for: let you easily manage structured information.

Ok, that doesn't mean that this is impossible as databases use files. May be, at first approximation you can: read **all** the file and parse it to structured data in memory, then manage that data and when needed write the data in a fresh file. Of course this is not a serious implementation if you have too many data.

Answer (score 1):

This is just some general reasoning as answer to the final "Maybe it would be better to ...":

Any simple implementation will be a bit fragile, but if you have very good control over input file, and risk of possible data damage doesn't bother you too much (i.e. damages will be low and easy to restore/repair), you may get away even with string replacement, searching for "Age=34\n" and replacing it with "Age=35\n" (if there's only single Age line in the file, otherwise you need first to locate correct person) ... reading whole file into memory first, then writing it back after replace.

Going for JSON will give you more safety over structure (no chance to accidentally change "CarnAge=34" instead of "Age=34"), yet JSON is still sort of editable in plain text editor (if you are careful enough). Also JSON is quite popular way to exchange data with web services. And this paragraph does apply for XML as well, although in terms of plain text edit I think JSON is a tad easier to learn for non programmers. So the "ini" would do, but I still prefer JSON.

And finally if this is anything more serious, considering some database would make lot of sense. Those are verified solutions to quite effectively store/modify/fetch data, being much more efficient with file I/O than naive read/write whole file (DB are handling files in a way allowing them to modify content by overwriting just parts of it, by keeping reserve space around and having mechanism to completely restructure part of some file). Plus most of the DBs are [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), so adding additional robustness to your app "for free". You just can't edit the data in plain text (but you can still prepare data in some sheet, and import them trough some DB manager tool).

The only reasons why to avoid some common DB - I can think of - are: 1) performance (in special cases a good programmer will outperform professional DB engine, but most of the time it's not worth the huge effort involved), 2) project is too small/tutorial, so while integrating for example "sqlite" is not that difficult, just reading whole file and replacing string is even simpler. But for example I write my C++ projects with U++ framework, so adding SQL would be a breeze of few additional lines, no huge hassle...

Comment: Thank you for the well thought trough answer! It would be good to use a database, but the project is very small and setting up a DB is not in the scope. I think I'll take your suggestion, and when I want to modify a value, I just recreate the whole file now with the edited string.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
ifstream ifs("e:\\file.txt");
vector<string> file;    
string temp;

while(getline(ifs, temp))
{
    if(temp.compare(0,4,"Age=")==0)
        temp.replace(0, sizeof("Age=125"),"Age=125");

        file.push_back(temp);
}
ifs.close();

ofstream ofs("e:\\file.txt");
for(auto begin = file.begin(), end = file.end(); begin!=end; begin++)
    ofs << *begin << endl;

ofs.close();
```